# In Typescript how to define a function type that allows arbitrary preceding params before a required param?

Tags: typescript

I want to define a function type that allows arbitrary arguments preceding a required argument
example:

```
type Op = (...args, required: A) => void
```

I am hoping to have behaviour of the following kind:

```
const foo:Op = (a.b,c, required: A) => void // this should compile
const foo:Op = (a.b,c:A) => void // this should compile
const foo:Op = (a.b,c) => void // this should not compile
```

I tried:

```
type Op = (required:A) => string
```

but these throw a type mismatch error:

```
let foo: Op = (a, b:A) => {return ""} //error
let foo: Op = (a, required:A) => {return ""} // error
```

I tried other ways of defining the type hoping to get lucky

```
type Op = (...args: any[], required:A) => string //error 

interface Op {
  (...args: any[], required:A): string //error
}
```

none of them worked.

Is there a way to do this in Typescript? Or am I trying something that is conceptually irreconcilable?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're out of luck. Even doing something like this...

```
interface A {
    x: number
}

type Op = ((a, b, c, required: A) => string) 
        | ((a, b, required: A) => string) 
        | ((a, required: A) => string) 
        | ((required: A) => string);


let foo: Op = (a, b:A) => "";
let bar: Op = (a, b:number) => ""; // not an error :-(
```

... won't work because [missing parameters don't fail the type check](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters).